# Attempted to read or write protected memory and out of memory issues

Tags: c#, memory-management

We have a new development server which a lot of our projects are developed on, and as of today I've noticed something very unusual. A piece of code which used to work perfectly is now throwing the following error:

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

The line it happens on is actually calling a method in an external API (Sage 200 SDK), so I thought it was an issue with that. However, the problem does not happen on any other machine, even though it's going to the same database with the same logins etc.

Something else I've noticed today is that I'm getting a lot of 'Out of memory' exceptions on some lengthy 'Foreach' parts of my code, so it seems like the .NET garbage collector isn't working correctly as again, I do not have this problem on other servers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not much to go on... Make more attempts to reproduce the problem on another machine. Is the affected machine serving more requests that unaffected machines?

Comment: Sorry, I know it's a rather vague question. The machine in question is actually much less 'active' then others I've tried it on.

Comment: It could be that you do actually have some dodgy memory or issue with the O/S that's causing these errors.  Or maybe it is actually out of memory (due to something else allocating lots) and allocation failures are badly handled in the code.

Comment: I, too am having this issue. ChrisH, did you find a solution to the above question?